# How to drop replication on multiple databases

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have several hundred databases that are stuck in Recovery Pending mode and will not drop due to replication. I've searched far and wide for a script that will drop replication on all databases and I even tried creating my own but not luck. Reaching out because I am out of options.

Comment: I would post this over at -> https://dba.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

This may work, however, I would post this over at DBA.stackexchange because this may be more of an X Y question.

```
EXECUTE master.sys.sp_MSforeachdb 'USE [?]; EXEC sp_removedbreplication ?'
```